# How are glycosidic linkages formed?

Tags: biochemistry, chemical-biology, carbohydrates

Consider glycosidic linkages in disaccharides.

I know a condensation reaction occurs, with the loss of water.

But which OH is lost? The O in the linkage belongs to which monosaccharide?

Example: take sucrose, the O in the linkage belongs to fructose or glucose?

I couldn't find any literature regarding this. Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sucrose molecule the  glycosidic linkage is formed by the OH group on the anomeric carbon of α-D-glucose and the OH group on the anomeric carbon of β-D-fructose.

[image]

source :

https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(McMurry)/Chapter_25%3A_Biomolecules%3A_Carbohydrates/25.08_Disaccharides

As seen, in either alpha d-glucose or beta d-fructo furanose may react to give sucrose.

Let us examin.

Alpha D-gluco Pyranose gives an intermediate **1** and **2** by protonation at anomeric carbon.

[image]

Similarly  Beta D-fructo furanose gives an intermediate **3** and **4** by protonation at anomeric carbon.
[image]

If you examine , structure 3 is more stable then structure 4.

[image]

The negative inductive effect of CH2OH in fructofuranose destablizes this intermediate 4.

Hence structure 2 , an intermediate of aplha D-gluco pyranose (**more stable**) attacks beta D-fructo furanose togive sucrose.

[image]

---

The above diagrams are author drawn in CHEM DRAW

Comment: This entire answer appears to be copy-pasted from Bruice's *Organic chemistry*. If you are quoting third-party sources, or using any graphics/data/plots that are not made by you, put an appropriate reference and denote the part that is quoted with proper markup (`>`). Keep in mind that if you don't that you may eventually be accused of plagiarism.

Comment: @user226375 your question is answered now,

Comment: @andselisk you were correect .This was taken from  Bruice's Organic chemistry.(missed reference ).How ever the answer is rewritten ti the question asked .The diagrams are mine , drawn on CHEMDRAW.

Comment: @andselisk I MISSED QUOTING REFERENECE IN HURRY TO ANSWER .MY APOLOGIES .THIS WAS NOT DONE ON PURPOUSE.