# Where does the beta notation come from in the alpha 1,2 beta glycosidic bond (in sucrose)?

Tags: biochemistry, carbohydrates

[image]

I am confused as to where the beta is coming from (in the alpha-1,2-beta glycosidic bond in sucrose). I understand that the alpha is from the anomeric carbon of the glucose, but I don't see how the beta is part of this

To me it seems as though the hydroxyl on the anomeric carbon of fructose (i.e. th OH below the plane of C-2 in fructose) causes it to be an alpha form, correct? If so, then why is it called a beta linkage?

Comment: The figure in your post is not that clear. See the section on Sucrose here. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/115942/how-are-glycosidic-linkages-formed

Comment: @M. Farooq: The video you recommended gives the wrong loss of water for the formation of maltose from glucose. Your second response answers the OP's question.

Comment: @user55119, I deleted the link. The video was of low quality anyway.